# Convert MS Powerpoint presentation to a video using C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, office-interop

Is there a way to convert a pptx to a video file with all slide animations.
I tried following code, but it complains about `CreateVideo` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV`.

Is this possible with new Interop implementations and is there other alternatives?

```html
string fileName = @"C:\Presentation1.pptx";
            string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
            string exportPath = @"C:\{0}.wmv";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(
              fileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            try
            {
                oPres.CreateVideo(exportName);
                oPres.SaveCopyAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName),
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV,
                    MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
            }
            finally
            {
                ppApp.Quit();
            }
```

Error   CS1061  '_Presentation' does not contain a definition for 'CreateVideo' and no accessible extension method 'CreateVideo' accepting a first argument of type '_Presentation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0117  'PpSaveAsFileType' does not contain a definition for 'ppSaveAsWMV'

Comment: Can you elaborate on "complains"?

Comment: See at the bottom for compile errors, thanks

Comment: You code compiles and runs for me. Though it does not create valid video.

Comment: /Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint/12.0.4518.1014
Powerpoint 365 version 16
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Office/12.0.0

These are my versions. I get compile time errors